# Evaluate $\iiint_R z \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dV $ where $R$ is the solid hemisphere that lies above the xy-plane with center at the origin and radius of 1

Tags: calculus

Here $R$ is the solid hemisphere that lies above the $xy$-plane with center at the origin and radius of $1$.  Does that means the range of $x,y,z$ are $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

No.

It means that the integration domain is $\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1 ,z\geq 0\}$.

Based on the form of the integrand, spherical coordinates is advised.